# Number of students with better grades and lower jee rank

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming

We are given n students with cgpa (college grades) and jee ranks (Rank in admission exam) of every student.
For every student, we have to calculate the number of students who have better cgpa but worse jee rank.

(x1,y1), (x2,y2) ...(xi,yi)... (xn,yn)

for each i, we have to calculate no. of j for which xj > xi and yj > yi (worse rank means greater rank.)

I could come up with the following nlogn algorithm-
    Sort them decreasing cgpa.
    Now start scanning from left.
    Maintain the students scanned so far in a balanced binary tree (according to their jee     rank).
    For the next student, just find out the no of students already scanned with greater rank by querying the balanced binary tree.

I don't know how to maintain a balanced bst in which i can return no. of elements less than k in O(logn). We would need to maintain no. of nodes in subtree at each node. But how to do that?

Either help with the above or else provide a different algorithm, perhaps DP.

Comment: How do you intend to find a list of students who have better CGPA but worse grades? It doesn't sound logical to me. How can CGPA be inversely proportional to rank?

Comment: CGPA means grades in college, and rank refers to the rank among all students who appeared for the admission test of that college.
The two have no relation between them.

Comment: `For the next student, just find out the no of students already scanned with greater rank by querying the balanced binary tree` you can't have a same balanced tree for different attributes.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri the binary tree is different. When i am scanning the students in decreasing order of cgpa, after calculating the no of students with greater cgpa but worse rank, i am adding him to the binary tree (maintained on jee rank).

Comment: @NitinGarg I mean these are irrelevant, in fact there isn't any common issue between this two attributes, Also when you sort something in fact you can have the balanced binary tree in O(n) so sorting and balanced bst are same approach in O(n) which is smaller than n log n. I mean you can't do this with one sorted list and bst, If you can would you clarify your way by example?

Comment: All you need to do is write a proper `Comparator` and do a sort on the list of students. The solution for the student[i] is `size of list - i`. Why do you need a BST?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to code balanced binary tree, Binary Indexed Tree (aka BIT or Fenwick Tree) is the DS you should be looking at. It can be coded in < 10 easy lines. [Here](http://yellowagony.blogspot.com/2011/02/prefix-sums-fenwick-trees.html) is a blog post I wrote on Fenwick Trees that might help.